# C# NullReference Exception and ReSharper suggestion

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, resharper

This is what I have written:

```
if ((lstProperty[i].PropertyIdentifier as string).CompareTo("Name") == 0)
```

Resharper put me an error (I am new with ReSharper... I am trying it) and it suggests me :

```
  if (((string) lstProperty[i].PropertyIdentifier).CompareTo("Name") == 0)
```

Why is the second is NullException safe? For me both will crash if null value appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'as' operator will return null if the cast cannot be executed, while a C-style cast will throw an exception if it can't cast.

I suggest breaking this out into multiple statements:

```
string propertyIdentifier = lstProperty[u].PropertyIdentifier as string;
if(propertyIdentifier != null && propertyIdentifier.CompareTo("Name") == 0)
{
    ... your if statement ...
}
```

Resharper shouldn't complain about this, and you also won't get a NullReferenceException if the PropertyIdentifier is null or not a string.

Answer (score 5):

Both examples will succeed or fail in the same circumstances, and when they succeed, the behavior will be identical.

When they fail, the result will be slightly different: the second example fails slightly earlier (at the cast), and with a more specific exception (`InvalidCastException` vs. `NullReferenceException`).

The main benefit is for debugging: when they fail, you have more information about why it failed in the second example than in the first.  Specifically, if the PropertyIdentifier is `null` vs. non-`string`, you can tell in the second case, but not in the first case.

Also, if you are in a `try/catch`, you can handle the non-`string` case in a separate code path than the `null` case.  However, you probably shouldn't be coding this way: if you are, you're doing something else wrong.

It might help illuminate the situation if you step through the following code in the various cases:

```
var propertyI = lstProperty[i];
var propertyIdentifier = propertyI.PropertyIdentifier;

// pick one of these:
var propertyIdentifierAsString = propertyIdentifier as string;
var propertyIdentifierAsString = (string)propertyIdentifier;

if (propertyIdentifierAsString.CompareTo("Name") == 0)
```